# Show dialog over system dialog("Just once or always")

Tags: android

I want to recreate the same thing as ApusLauncher where they display a dialog above the "Just once or always" dialog
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Czp15.png)

The thing is that they don't request any permission in order to display this dialog, which I am not able to recreate. While you are on the screen [as on the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Czp15.png), if you click anywhere(including the system dialog on the bottom) on the screen, the dialog is **first closed**, only then you can perform a click. I have tried this myself but every time my dialog is being put in the background(under dark overlay) . This works for Apus on **any** API level

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

this looks like an ongoing notification with high priority (look at https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/time-sensitive)
which has a custom view.

another possible option is to add a view directly to window manager but then you will have to have the "draw over other application" permission.

Comment: That is a one way of doing it but i don't think this is the way they did it, since nothing shows up in the notification bar, also when I disable notifications in system settings, the dialog still shows up. Do you have any other ideas maybe? Thank you.